# Determine if the function $f$ is even, odd or neither given the graph of $f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The following picture is a graph of a function $f$. I am to determine whether the function is even, odd, or neither. I reasoned that $f$ is odd, because if the graph is rotated $\pi$ radians, the graph is reproduced perfectly. The graph is clearly not even, because it is not symmetrical with respect to the vertical axis. However, the solution states that $f$ is neither even or odd, and I do not understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're right that the graph has a symmetry - if you rotate about a certain point on the $y$-axis, you preserve the graph. Algebraically, it has the property:
$$f(x)=2c-f(-x)$$
where $c=f(0)$ is the intersection of the graph and the $y$-axis. The condition of *oddness* is more strict, however, it demands:
$$f(x)=-f(-x)$$
meaning the function must have this rotational symmetry about the *origin*, not about some arbitrary point. Note that oddness implies $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Why do you have $2c$ instead of just $c$ if $c$ represents the intersection of the graph with the $y$-axis?

Comment: For parity, the definition of *evenness* is:
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$

By the way, looking at your plot, I think you have a cubic function, not a sinusoid. However, assuming that $f(x)=\sin(x)+y_0$, your statements still hold:

$$f(x)=\sin(x)+y_0$$
$$f(-x)=\sin(-x)+y_0=-\sin(x)+y_0$$
$$f(x) \neq f(-x) \rightarrow not ~ even$$
$$f(x) \neq -f(-x) \rightarrow not ~ odd$$

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire I wrote it that way since if you want to "reflect" a value $x$ across a mirror at $c$, the resulting value is $2c-x$. More algebraically, note that at $f(0)$ this identity says $f(0)=2c-f(0)$ so rearranging gives $2f(0)=2c$.

Answer (score 3):

> "I reasoned that $f$ is odd, because if the graph is rotated $\pi$ radians, the graph is reproduced perfectly."

It sounds like you were rotating around  the $y$-intercept.  To test for oddness, you **always** want to rotate around the origin.  A quick test for non-oddness is to look at the origin.  If the graph doesn't go through the origin, the function is not odd.  If the graph does go through the origin then the function may or may not be odd.  It is in this case that you'll need to check the rotation of $\pi$ radians.

Comment: Yep. So, the function $x\mapsto f(x) -f(0)$ is odd